# prevent EMACS LaTeX mode from indenting pycode environment?

Tags: python

I'm using `pythontex` to allow me to embed Python code in LaTeX files. (It's really great, BTW.) I edit my LaTeX with EMACS. Unfortunately, EMACS thinks that any environment should be indented, and if I have indent within `\begin{pytex}`...`\end{pytex}`, it generates a Python error.

That is, EMACS thinks this is correct:

```
\begin{pycode}
   print("Hello World!")
\end{pycode}
```

But in fact, this is correct:

```
\begin{pycode}
print("Hello World!")
\end{pycode}
```

What do I put in Config-File to prevent the `pycode` environment from being indented?

Answer (score 2):

```
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments "pycode")
(add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list
        '("pycode" current-indentation))
```

Comment: `Symbol’s value as variable is void: LaTeX-verbatim-environments`

Comment: `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0) of 2018-10-07`

Comment: Any thoughts? The variable doesn't seem to be there in my version of the latex mode.

Comment: On my machine, this works just fine (Arch Linux, also Emacs 26.1)! What's the output, when you run emacs with `emacs -q` and then evaluate the above code?

Comment: `Symbol’s value as variable is void: LaTeX-verbatim-environments` is what I get.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask to migrate this question.

Comment: @wy32 You both should also compare the output of `M-x locate-library <RET> latex <RET>`.